# C# JSON deserialize objects, when number is unkown

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a JSON-file like this:

```
{ "object": {
  "child1": "one",
  "child2": "two",
  "child3": "three",
  "ChildObjects": null
}}
```

And here are my c# classes:

```
    public class jsonClass1
    {
        public string child1 { get; set; }
        public string child2 { get; set; }
        public string child3 { get; set; }
        public ChildObjects ChildObject { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildObjects
    {
        public ChildObjects ChildObject { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildObject
    {
        public string variable1 { get; set; }
        public string variable2 { get; set; }
    }
```

So if there is no childObjects, i dont have any problems to deserialize the json. but sometimes the JSON-file looks like this:

```
  { "object": {
      "child1": "one",
      "child2": "two",
      "child3": "three",
      "childObjects": {
        "[0]ChildObject": {
          "variable1": "value1",
          "variable2": "value2"
        },
        "[1]ChildObject": {
          "variable1": "value1",
          "variable2": "value2"
        }
      }
}}
```

So my question now is: how to deserialize when numbers of objects is unknown (0 to x)?

Comment: If you know the names to be unique, you could serialise into a dictionary. JSON.net should support that

Comment: That's the oddest array definition I've ever seen in JSON.

Comment: 1) Use array instead of object in "childObjects"
or
2) Use dictionary of every object in "childObjects"